# Leading significant digits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, geometry, logarithmic-scale, ssstriangle

Given that the initial area in a [`Sierpinski triangle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) is A_0 and the subsequent areas
$$(A_n) =A_0 (3/4)^n$$ ,
what is the formula to calculate the leading significant digits of the areas $A_1,A_2,…,A_n$, following [`Benford's Law`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)?
After some readings, I intuitively attempted the formula

```
d=10^(Floor[〖log〗_10 (A_n )])
```

but for `n=1` and `A_0 = 100`, we get `d = 10`, when we know that the leading significant digit of $A_1$ (which we understand to be the leading digit) is 7.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

To get the areas of the triangles we may define a function:

```
a[0]=100;
a[n_]= a[0] (3/4)^n;
```

To get the first digits, we may use the function "RealDigits". With this we get the 10000 first digits like:

```
dat = Table[RealDigits[a[i], 10, 1][[1, 1]], {i, 0, 10000}];
```

A histogram shows, that these are approx. ditributed according to Benford's Law:

```
Histogram[dat]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

"1" is approx. 30%

"2" is approx. 17.6%

"3" is approx. 12.5%

....

Comment: You will get more reasonable results if you increase the sample size to 10^5 or more. Statistics work better for large samples.

Comment: @Bob Halon You are 100% right. I changed my answer accordingly.